# How do I include my firebase service account key when using functions.config().firebase to init?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm initializing my firebase functions like so:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
```

I've generated a service account key which I believe I need to do for auth purpouses.

It gave me a json table with various key/values.

The instructions were to add that in admin.initializeApp like so:

```
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Which is very different to how I'md oing it.

I'm not even sure I need to do this though because I do have access to firestore using my previous method, however auth with valid user id tokens is not working giving me the following error in firebase:

> ERROR: Error: Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed
>   the entire string JWT which represents an ID token. See
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for
>   details on how to retrieve an ID token.

and from sniffing around it looked like the missing thing was the admin sdk service account..

Comment: Looks like the ID token passed to `verifyIdToken()` is malformed somehow. Can you try logging it in the server-side and see what turns up?

Answer (score 4):

This snippet is a general way to initialize the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js:

```
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

As you've seen, it requires that you download a JSON file from the console, and add it to the path.

This is a bit finicky, and some developers find it hard to get working. Since the Cloud Functions environment is fully under Firebase's control, it was made a bit easier there. Your other snippet shows how:

```
admin.initializeApp()
```

Both snippets accomplish the same thing, but the latter only works in Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Comment: ah, so does this mean if I use the former example you've provided where credential is explicitly passed in my issue should be solved? I did try that method but had the same error pop up..

Comment: Decoding a JWT should be possible with either approach. The problem is likely elsewhere in your code. As Hiranya commented, enable debug logging to see what it shows. If it remains a problem, I'd recommend opening a separate question with the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Looks like admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase) works, when I moved the aws function to be inside cors it suddenly started working. not sure why though.